# What programs and or assistance is available to family when homemaker becomes disabled?

Tags: united-states, insurance, disability

If a non-working spouse, homemaker/parent, becomes seriously ill (cancer) and disabled, what programs, assistance, insurance are available to such a family? A family **not** living below poverty line (median income household).

I have searched online, and it appears one would need several months of emergency funds. Disability insurance near impossible, SDI not available as no work history, etc.

Comment: That varies dramatically by state and locality, as different areas have different levels of willingness to help neighbors.

Comment: Are you planning ahead and trying to mitigate this risk, or are you already in the situation you describe? The advice will differ if you are just planning ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, disability insurance for a non-working spouse is unusual, but this [article](https://myfamilylifeinsurance.com/2018/12/08/best-disability-insurance-for-stay-at-home-moms-and-homemakers/) points to [Illinois Mutual](https://www.illinoismutual.com/Learning-Center/Life-Events/Stay-at-Home-Spouses) as a carrier that offers it.

Federal disability benefits can be applied for: https://www.ssa.gov/disability/

Other government benefits: For the working spouse to take over the home duties, *unpaid* family leave is available to private company employees through [FMLA](https://www.dol.gov/general/topic/benefits-leave/fmla). [Thirteen US states](https://www.metlife.com/insurance/disability-insurance/paid-family-medical-leave/states/) require some version of *paid* family leave.

Regarding charity, a web search for 'cancer charity family' may lead to local charities. Nationally, https://www.cancersupportcommunity.org/ and https://www.cancercare.org/ offer guides. Despite being middle income, the family can seek out a food pantry where they are eligible or where no questions are asked: https://www.feedingamerica.org/